# Docker - How is it possible to make/make install an extension in a Docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-extensions

I am using the `posgres:10.0` image to run PostgreSQL inside a container. My `docker-compose.yml` looks fairly simple:

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:10.0"
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
    - ./volumes/postgresql/postgresql.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgresql.sh
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

**postgresql.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo wal_level=logical              >> $PGDATA/postgresql.auto.conf
echo max_replication_slots=1        >> $PGDATA/postgresql.auto.conf
echo host replication all all trust >> $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf
```

For my project, we will start using the Multicorn extension, see http://multicorn.org/. To make/make install this, I need to do:

```
git clone git://github.com/Kozea/Multicorn.git
cd Multicorn
make && make install
```

Then afterwards, I can add a `multicorn.sql` script and add it to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory, which will be called when the Docker container is starting up:

```
CREATE EXTENSION multicorn;
```

But how can I make/make install Multicorn within the Docker container? Ideally, I want to keep using the `posgres:10.0` and not invent/create my own version, as I don't want to inherit the maintenance hassle.

Comment: I think you're going to have to maintain your own docker file artifact.  But I'm curious about what the world will say about this.

Comment: Did you find a easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an own Dockerfile - this is the sense of Dockerfiles ;) Otherwise you would have to do some hacking with scripts at startup or something like this. Don't do that...

Another quick note: If you want to build it from source, you might want to have a look at this and use a multi-stage docker build: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: About multi-stage builds: would it work to create a temporary container with postgresql installed, make/make install the extension in that temporary container and then copy the extension from `/usr/lib/postgresql/x.y/lib/...` to the same directory of the target/final container?